# Finding positive $a$ such that the remainder of $x^3-x^2+ax$ when divided by $x+a$ is twice its remainder when divided by $x-2a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given that the remainder when $x^3-x^2+ax$ is divided by $x+a$, where $a > 0$, is twice the remainder when it is divided by $x-2a$. Find the value of $a$.

Comment: If you say **please**, do not use *punctuation mark*. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, please sir may I have another?

Comment: Can you do polynomial division? Because if you cannot, then it's probably better if you focus on some easier problems first.

Comment: Yes for polynomial division :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I shall assume that you know how to perform polynomial division. So $$\frac{a x+x^3-x^2}{a+x}=\frac{-a^3-2 a^2}{a+x}-(a+1) x+a (a+2)+x^2$$ $$\frac{a x+x^3-x^2}{x-2 a}=\frac{2 \left(4 a^3-a^2\right)}{x-2 a}+(2 a-1) x+a (4 a-1)+x^2$$

I am sure that you can take from here. Include the condition and solve for $a$

Answer (score 0):

Using remainder theorem,we have-
$$x+a =0$$
$$\implies x= -a$$
$$\therefore f(a)=-a^3+a^2-a^2=-a^3$$
$\therefore$ the remainder when $x^3-x^2+ax$ is divided by $x+a$ is $-a^3$
$$Now$$
Again using remainder theorem we have-
$$x-2a=0$$
$$\implies x= 2a$$ 
$$f(2a)=(2a)^3-(2a)^2+2a^2=8a^3-4a^2+2a^2$$$$=8a^3-2a^2=2a^2(4a-1)$$
$\therefore$ the remainder when $x^3-x^2+ax$ is divided by $x-2a$ is $2a^2(4a-1)$
Now you can proceed according to the given condition to obtain the value of a.